# Java EE Security framework without involving the server

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I was looking into the security model of Java EE. It seems that the model involves configuring the web server (I am using glassfish 4.0).

What I am looking for is a security framework which I can add without any configuration of the server. For example-

I might pass my database credentials when starting the web application to one of the configuration classes of that framework, then I can call methods like- user.isAuthenticated() etc.

Another side question is, if I am using hibernate orm and also the Java EE security model then my hibernate is configured to connect to database and also my glassfish server is connected to the database. So is there any way I can skip connecting to the database only with hibernate but also use a security framework?

Comment: Take a look at spring security http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Comment: @cgon Thanks, looks like what I am looking for.

Comment: @Tiny I do not have any intention to underestimate container managed authentication. I was just looking for another way to do it. I will also upgrade my glassfish server. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a minimal familiarity with Spring Framework, take a look a [this](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/) tutorial

There isn't server involvement. You can implement your own          user.isAuthenticated() method.

Comment: Thanks the tutorial was helpful :) Though I need a little bit more time to understand spring security.